# Making JQuery dialog position as fixed

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm new to using JQuery and in my application we already have a jquery dialog implemented at some place. By default I see that Jquery dialog position is absolute and I want to customize this to fixed position specific to my dialog. I have tried defining a new dialog class with the customized position but still it did not work..any help is greatly appreciated...thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome! Maybe you want to include some of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Glad to share that the above mentioned issue is resolved by myself.

In the default function (ui.dialog.js file) , instead of defaulting position attribute to 'absolute' value , I have initialized this attribute with the parameter being passed from invoking function. Where ever, this function is invoked, I have added position attribute to the required value.

// below is the sample code

```js
function custmsgbox(id,title,msg){
 var str=' jq(function() {';
 str=str+'jq("#' + id + '").dialog({';
 str=str+'autoOpen: false, ';
 str=str+'closeOnEscape: false, ';
 str=str+'modal: true,'; 
 str=str+'title: "'+title+'",';
 str=str+'position: ' + " \'fixed\', ";
 str=str+' width:370,';
 str=str+'maxHeight:100,';
    ---
    ---
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
uiDialog = (this.uiDialog = $('<div/>'))
    .appendTo(document.body)
    .hide()
    .addClass(uiDialogClasses + options.dialogClass)
    .css({
     position: options.position,
     overflow: 'hidden',
     zIndex: options.zIndex
    })
```